# MailMessage Delete attachments after sending if in Path.GetTempPath()

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, smtpclient, mailmessage

Pardon my newness to the MailMessage and SmtpClient classes.  I've built something that basically works, but in preparing to send the attachments, I sometimes copy the attachments to the temporary files location (`Path.GetTempPath() + @"\" + timestampWithFF`), because they sometimes must be zipped to send.  When this happens, I want to make sure I delete the files there after sending (especially because anything there is going to be relatively large).

Two-fold question:
1.  should I not bother with cleaning up the files because the OS (win7) will do a good job of it?
2.  how can I get the HDD location of the Attachments in `client.SendCompleted`?

```
client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    client.Dispose();
    foreach(Attachment a in msg.Attachments)
    {
        // want to actually delete the file from the HDD if it's in Path.GetTempPath();
    }
    msg.Dispose();
};
```

I see I could use `a.Dispose()`, but I don't have any idea what it does...I suspect it's disposing of the object (which `msg.Dispose` would do next anyways), but would leave the files on the HDD.

must I send the filepaths of the attachments separately?
the `client.SendCompleted()` line is in: 
`sendMailAsync(SmtpClient client, MailMessage msg)` method.  I could change this to:
`sendMailAsync(SmtpClient client, MailMessage msg, List<string> attachments)`
and add this to the `SendCompleted()`, but it feels kinda clunky:

```
string tempDir = Path.GetTempPath();
foreach(string f in attachments)
{
    if(f.Contains(tempDir))    // want to actually delete the file from the HDD if it's in Path.GetTempPath();
    {
        if (File.Exists(f)) { File.Delete(f); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. should I not bother with cleaning up the files because the OS (win7) will do a good job of it?

If i were you, I would still delete the temp file, though OS would clean it, when it deems necessary

> 2. how can I get the HDD location of the Attachments in client.SendCompleted?

The files in the attachments can be retrieved through `ContentStream`. Their type would be of `FileStream`.

```
client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    client.Dispose();
    var fileattachments = msg.Attachments
                          .Select(x => x.ContentStream)
                          .OfType<FileStream>()
                          .Select(fs => fs.Name)
                          .ToArray();

    msg.Dispose();

    string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
    foreach (var attachment in fileattachments )
    {
        if(attachment.Contains(tempPath)
        {
            File.Delete(attachment);
        }

    }
};
```

**Note:** First dispose the `msg` object and then do the deletion

Comment: hmmm... this seems so close to right, but I'm getting zero elements from the Select.  I think it required a .ToArray() (or similar) after Select(fs =>fs.Name) because otherwise fileattachments isn't evaluated until after msg.Dispose, so there's nothing to loop over.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I wrote it out of my head remembering the old days i worked upon it and totally missed `.ToArray();`. Thanks for the edit! :) hope this worked out for u after adding `ToArray`